# Перевод из Jquery в Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка. Вроде правильно из JQuery в JavaScript перевёл:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('txt')).forEach(e => e.innerHTML = function(i, html) {
  var chars = $.trim(html).split("");

  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы, вероятно, ожидаете, что мы догадаемся, как выглядит скрипт jQuery, который Вы переводите.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.txt').forEach(e => {
  var chars = e.textContent.split("");
  e.innerHTML = '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: а, ой извините , вот

Comment: $('.txt').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = $.trim(html).split("");

  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});

Comment: @КостяХарчук Код - в вопрос. Впрочем, я уже ответил. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: благодарю, выручили, огромное спасибо